# Логика работы фрагментов

Tags: java, android

Я новичок.
Пытаюсь понять логику.
В майАтивити имеется две кнопки, по  нажатию срабатывает открытие фрагмента1, и закрытие фрагмента 2. И наоборот.
Из фрагмента Я возвращаю не только виджет, но и данные у этом вилдете.

Comment: Мне нужно с МайнАктивити по клику на кнопку перейти на этот фрагент и уже с внесенными данными

Comment: нет, `onCreate()` [выполняется **до**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru#Creating) `onCreateView()`/ Сформулируйте свой вопрос подробнее, чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ